# Sytem.Runtime.InteropServices.ExtrnalException: 'Error genérico en GDI+'

Tags: c#, gdi

Estoy tratando de convertir una imagen de un picturebox a Base64 con el siguiente código

```
public static string ImageToBase64String(Image imagen)
{
    using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        imagen.Save(ms, imagen.RawFormat);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    }
}
```

El problema es que me da el error:

> Sytem.Runtime.InteropServices.ExtrnalException: 'Error genérico en
>   GDI+'.

El código funciona cuando hago

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ofd.NameFile);
```

Esa imagen la logro guardar en base64 en un campo blob de mySql, cuando la recupero de la base de datos la convierto a imagen con el siguiente código:

```
    public static Image Base64StringToImage(string stringBase64)
    {
        var imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(stringBase64);
        using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
        {
            return Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        }
    }
```

Esa función me retorna una imagen y la coloco en el pictureBox, pero cuando intento volver a convertirla a base64 es cuando me da el error.